# Regex with range negative value to positive

Tags: regex

Hi I need to create regex that will match numbers in range -1 to 1, chat got problem with that and also i didn't find many answers.

Now I'm stuck because my regex match also -1.5 and 1.5 value but it shouldn't, my current regex is: `^-?1(\.0+)?|^-?0(\.[0]+)?$`

Comment: With JavaScript or Java? Why not just convert the value to number and then check the range?

Comment: Also, please clarify what format of values is allowed: are you expecting any form of decimal number with leading zeroes? Is exponential for acceptable? If yes, clarify exact expected format of it. Are decimal delimiters always `.`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^-?1(\.0+)?|^-?0(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Explanation:

- `^` asserts the start of the string.
- `-?` matches an optional minus sign.
  `1(\.0+)?` matches the number 1 followed by an optional decimal point and one or more zeros.
- `|` is the alternation operator, allowing matching either the previous pattern or the next pattern.
- `^-?0(\.[0-9]+)?$` matches the number 0 or a decimal number between -1 and 1.

Examples of matching numbers using this regex:

-1

-0.5

0

0.5

1

Examples of non-matching numbers:

-1.5

1.5

-2

2

Answer (score 1):

The first alternative in your pattern is missing the anchor `$`

To match all the values in between, you can match either 1 followed by `.` and 1+ zeroes, or match optional zeroes followed by `.` and 1+ digits:

```
^-?(?:1(?:\.0+)?|0+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `1(?:\.0+)?` Match 1 with an optional part matching `.` and 1+ zeroes
  - `|` Or
  - `0+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1 with an optional part matching `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ch6hK6/1).

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are **properly formatted** decimals, all you need is
`^-?(0|1|0\.\d+)$`

---

However, if they are not...
Ignoring `^$` bounds and optional `-?` which are always the same, you need:

- `1(\.0*)?` - to parse `1`, `1.`, `1.0`
- `0?\.\d+` - to parse `0.123`, `.123`
- `0\.\d*` - ro parse `0`, `0.`, `0.123`
- `\d+(\.\d*)?[eE]-\d+` - to parse `1e-12`, `1E-12`, `1.e-12`, `1.23e-12`

(all are valid numbers at least in Javascript)

resulting in `^-?(1(\.0*)?|0?\.\d+|0\.\d*|\d+(\.\d*)?[eE]-\d+)$`

(and it's still missing `0.123e1`, `12.3e-1` and `1e0` variants)